# Wordpress [ ] tags?

Tags: wordpress

I'm very new at wordpress and I'm trying to understand a code from a friend. I went to his wordpress account and edit some test page. However, the page has code inside [ ] tags. How can I edit it?

Here is an example from the wordpress wdit page:

```
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Test- #1 Business Communication App For Project Management &amp; Task Management</strong></p>
<strong>Important Notice:</strong> If you accessed ....</strong></em>, in order for your account to be properly updated.

[register_form]
```

How can I open/edit the [register_form] code?

Comment: Those are called template tags. There's a lot of information on the WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: @JonathanLandrum no, they're not. That's a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), as Reza Saadati correctly answered below.

Comment: @cabrerahector you are right

Answer (score 4):

This is a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) from a plugin or from your theme.

**Edit**

You can edit it in your theme. If the shortcode is from a plugin, you can overwrite it in your functions.php

```
function say(){
    return "Hello World";
}
add_shortcode( 'register_form', 'say' );
```

Comment: Do you know how can I open or find this plugin?

Comment: @MaxBoy if it is a plugin, you should never edit it! If it is a theme, you can create a child theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I need to add a AJAX request (call a webservice) after this [register_form] worked successfully. That's why I think I need to edit it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MaxBoy try looking inside your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Is there a way to call a web service after the shortcode?

Comment: @MaxBoy as long as you know the selector, you can add the Ajax to the JS file of your child theme. If you don't want a child theme, just add it to your theme but do not update the theme, otherwise your script may be lost.

Comment: What do you mean by know the selector?

Comment: @MaxBoy the class or the ID of your element.

Answer (score 1):

are the tags used to call a function of some plugin that you have active. that specific tag I do not recognize what plugin is, I recommend Contact Form 7, it is easy to use.

If you want to create a PHP function and use it on your page, create a plugin and declare the call as you want. But! Be careful as an error however small will damage your page.

for add tag on wordpress, from your plugin.

```
function NAME_FUNCTION(){...}
add_shortcode( 'NAME_FUNCTION', 'NAME_TAG' );
```

and call

```
[NAME_TAG]
```

Comment: OP's question isn't about how to create a shortcode but how to edit an existing one.

Comment: Go to Plugins, and check which of them is managing your contact forms. in the case of which I use "ContactForm 7", I can see it in the menu on the left of my wordpress, there I can create personalized forms and return a shortcode like this
    [contact-form-7 id="15370" title="Contact form 1"]